# javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function

Tags: python, selenium

The .click function is not working when it is executed. I would assume the css element is being found as the error, states that the `.click` function is not working.

I have tried a `.button(sendKeys)` option and that is not working either. This is the error I receive.

```
javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function
```

The argument takes a css selector and the `.click` should press that button.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    "#carousselArrow")
time.sleep(1)
# option 1: regular click
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elements)
```

Comment: You're doing `find_elements_` - s at the end - that means you're passing a `LIST` not an `ELEMENT` into the execute script.  Change your code to `find_element_` (no s) or use `elements[0]` as your input - both of those pick the first element returned

Comment: No unfortunately that is not it. I though it may be that so changed it to `elements` forgot to put it back to `element`

Comment: Update your question with exact issue as solution suggested by @RichEdwards should solve described issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is only one element.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#carousselArrow")
time.sleep(1)
for elem in element:
    elem.click()
```